# MongoDB: unconditional updates?

Tags: mongodb

This seems like a silly question but I haven't yet found the answer. If I simply wanted to add the same field->value to EVERY record in a MongoDB collection, what would be the appropriate shell command to do so? I tried doing a multi update with a blank query ({}) but that resulted in this error:

**multi update only works with $ operators**

I'm a bit puzzled about how to get around this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The error says it all: You can only modify multiple documents using the [`$` modifier operators](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations). You probably had something like this:

```
> db.coll.update({ }, { a: 'b' }, false, true);
```

Which would normally *replace* the first object in the collection with `{ a: 'b' }` if `multi` was false. You wouldn't want to replace all the objects in your collection with the same document!

Use the [`$set` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24set) instead:

```
> db.coll.update({ }, { '$set': { a: 'b' } }, false, true);
```

This will set the `a` property of every document (creating it as necessary) to `'b'`.